# Can passport authentication be done in .net?

Tags: .net

Can I do passport authentication in .net?

Comment: Do you have a question? If you have a problem in your code, post the code so we can see.

Comment: no, but i want only know this that is it possible in .net or not

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/532aee0e.aspx) - it is one of the authentication modes for asp.net.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - See [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/lmoningi/AuthenticationAndAuthorizatio11252005233533PM/AuthenticationAndAuthorizatio.aspx)

Comment: You may as well of posted a "Let me google that for you" URL :P